# Xfce: How to install US international keyboard with dead keys

Tags: 18.04, xfce, dead-keys

I am using Ubuntu Server (18.04) with Xfce desktop environment (via VNC) on my server, and I struggle to figure out how to change keyboard layout as you can see here. The only choice is US. Other options are also unchangeable

[image]

If I click the edit, this is how it looks

[image]

Comment: What happens if you click the Edit button?

Comment: Hi, please see updated post.

Comment: OK, someone with xfce will be able to check. You also cannot add different layouts, so this is definitely not a normal situation.

Comment: Thanks! Not sure if it is related to VNC server because I can't check if this happens with Desktop